# Redirecting https url

Tags: shared-hosting

At the moment we have a problem regarding a specific domain.

- `https://example.com` is showing directories;
- `https://example.com/forum/index.php` is showing the correct forum;
- `http://example.com` is being redirected to `https://example.com/forum/index.php`, which is OK.

As mentioned, `https://example.com` is showing directories which are located in the root dir (httpdocs)

```
<rule name="https file" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^example.com$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com/forum/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/forum/index.php " redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what your problem / desired behaviour is?

Comment: https://example.com should forward to: https://example.com/forum.index.php

Comment: Thought so ;) Please update your question accordingly to make it easier understandable.
Your problem could be related to your match-expression `^example.com$` requires the _whole_ URL to be `example.com`. Try `example.com$` or `^(http://|https://)?\.example.com$` The first one matches everything that ends with example.com (e.g. subdomain.example.com), the second one matches http/https exactly.

Comment: Thanks, we did manage to solve it another way. Through meta refresh ;D

Comment: You might want to put that in a more detailed answer to help others who stumble upon this :)